# qt when reading from file all data get deleted

Tags: file, qt

```
    void visualICDAR::open()
{QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( this, tr( "Open Image" ), 
        QDir::homePath(), tr("Images ( *.tif )") );

    if( !fileName.isEmpty() )
    {
        QApplication::setOverrideCursor( QCursor( Qt::WaitCursor ) );

        pixmapWidget->setPixmap( fileName );

        QString dataFileName = fileName.replace( fileName.length() - 3, 3, "csv" );

        QFile data( dataFileName );
        if( !data.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text) )
        {
            QMessageBox::warning( this, "NoCSV file founs!",
                QString( "No %1 file was found!" ).arg( dataFileName ) );
        }

        QTextStream text( &data );
        text.setCodec( "UTF-8" );

        QString dataString = text.readAll();

        ( (QStandardItemModel*)fileWidget->model() )->clear();
        fileWidget->AddRowsFromString( dataString );
        fileWidget->setOutputFile( dataFileName );

        data.close();

        QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
    }
}

    class CFileWidget : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CFileWidget(QWidget *parent);
    ~CFileWidget();

    void setOutputFile( const QString fileName ) 
        { outputFile.setFileName(fileName); 
    outputFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text); }

public slots:
    void AddRowsFromString( const QString& text );
    void DeleteSelectedRows();
    void AddRow();
    void SaveToFile();

signals:
    void SelectRects( const QList<QRect>& rects, const QList<QRect>& parenRects );

protected slots:
    void selectionChanged ( const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected );

private:
    int addonId;
    QFile outputFile;
};

    void CFileWidget::SaveToFile()
{
    QTextStream textStream( &outputFile );
    textStream.setCodec( "UTF-8" );

    for( int row = 0; row < ( (QStandardItemModel*)model() )->rowCount(); ++row )
    {
        int column = 0;

        while( ( (QStandardItemModel*)model() )->item( row, column ) )
        {
            textStream<<( (QStandardItemModel*)model() )->item( row, column )->data( Qt::DisplayRole ).toString();
            textStream<<"\t";
            column++;
        }

        textStream<<"\n";
    }
}
```

I am trying to read some data from file but when i read it the file gets empty.
Why does that happened?
If some error appear in program it will not save any data back and we will lose it?
So how to open file, read from it and keep all data in it?
As I understand if I open it again with write only mode i will rewrite all data not append?

about code
first function is for open file
second piece of code is class that stores QFile
and third is save to file function

Comment: Code you posted doesn't look really harmful and surely should lead to file content is lost. May be you open same file somewhere with Write options? To append use QIODevice::Append

Comment: after i read from file i close it but keep the file name
later in code i open that file with write only and text mode write data back.
it is just weird if i just opened it and code did not reached lines with save to file function, than i minimize my program, go to explorer and see that file i just opened is 0 size( but was 70 Kb )

Comment: Is it emptying the file pre or post read? And if you quit the application is the data gone completely?

Comment: it emptying post reading
and yeah i already lost one file that way

Comment: You should show minimal amount of code that clears the file. The code you show now, doesn't do that.

Comment: but i do not clear the file
it is not what i am want to do
after read all i use the data i found for some purpose and then close file
after i open it for write only

Comment: ok i will post more code

Answer (score 0):

Oki, what happens is that your program operates exactly as you asked it to do.. then you open file for reading using QIODevice::ReadOnly, you get data and nothing wrong happens.

Then you open it for Write you should decide (from application logic point of view) what do you want to do. If you want to overwrite file content you should use WriteOnly mode, which works in absolutely the same way as "w" mode in fopen() call, so it truncate file content on opening, so content will be lost as soon as file opened.

If you intent to keep content and add something, consider using Append mode, so you can add data file without loosing content.

Check this out: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum

Comment: file is empty between reading and writing
if error occur in that interval i lose everything

Comment: if file is properly closed after reading and error occurred before writing content of file could not be lost. If you OPEN a file for Writing and error occurs BEFORE you actually called write, then you loose a content..

Comment: the error occurs while i manipulating with data in program and do not press save to file button
the main question why if I read from file and then check in explorer the size of a file its zero
i worked with basic input\output functions in c and never met this problem

Answer (score -2):

Qt is just a IDE with its own encapsulated libraries, shouldn't be too different from normal file operations. Are you sure the file is empty or it looks like empty? I don't exactly remember what it is called, but data is first buffered, and needs to be pushed into a file, between these two procedures it looks like empty. If you open a file without turning on "append", and the program starts to run and quit, file would be empty. Once you open the file with append on, the pointer would point to the end.

Comment: to me, VS is also IDE with its own encapsulated libraries. no idea why some people are obsessed with name.

Comment: because if you want to be treated as professional developer I believe you should use at least proper terminology answering a question.. VS is indeed a IDE, although i don't see relation with mysterious 'encapsulated libraries'..

Comment: VS is an IDE, and Qt Creator is an IDE. Qt is an API and .NET is an API. Generally it's best to be specific in conversations with them as everything is searchable here. Just as an addition he's opening the file with the read only flag so setting append shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: file is empty in explorer
and as i said if there error and i did not save data to file the file is empty
no even previous data